# SQL comparing lists with lists

Tags: sql, left-join

I have 3 tables: `tbl_company`, `tbl_location`, `tbl_category`.
Each company is able to have more than 1 location and more than one category.

So the fields for the tables are as follows:

`tbl_company`: `co_id`, `title`

`tbl_location_member`: `loc_id`, `co_id`

`tbl_category_member`: `cat_id`, `co_id`

So my parameters is a list of categories ids and locations ids and the result should show the companies that meets the criteria.

My query looks like this:

```
SELECT  
      cc.co_id
      ,cc.title
      ,cc.subtitle

FROM tbl_company AS cc
LEFT JOIN tbl_category_member as cm ON cm.co_id = cc.co_id 
LEFT JOIN tbl_location_member as lm ON lm.co_id = cc.co_id 
WHERE publish=1
AND cm.cat_id  IN (14,16)
AND lm.loc_id IN (1,2)
```

The problem with this query is that it returns a company 4 times. 
The reason is because this company is meets all 4 criteria.
Is there any alternative way to accomplish thaT?

Comment: Move cm and lm conditions from WHERE to ON to get true left join behavior. (Now they executes as regular inner joins...)

Comment: Thank you for your help. Do you mean: `LEFT JOIN tbl_category_member as cm ON cm.cat_id  IN (14,16)` because this is messing up the query.

Comment: what means "meet the criteria"? That they have exactly these lists or that their list contain you parameter list?

Comment: At least one criteria for category AND for location. I mean the relation between location and category is `AND`

Comment: so if one meets cat_id=14 and loc_id=1 it should be in the result set?

Answer (score 0):

Should have been a comment, but I need more space...

```
SELECT  
      cc.co_id
      ,cc.title
      ,cc.subtitle
FROM tbl_company AS cc
LEFT JOIN tbl_category_member as cm ON cm.co_id = cc.co_id
                                   AND cm.cat_id  IN (14,16)
LEFT JOIN tbl_location_member as lm ON lm.co_id = cc.co_id
                                   AND lm.loc_id IN (1,2)
WHERE publish=1
```

Comment: It's not working either. Actually the logic is to get any companies that are located on X1,X2 locations and  are in  Y1,Y2,Y3 categories.

Comment: It wasn't intended to be the answer, just to show you how to do proper left joins.

Comment: the original join i a proper left join , too. It depends on what you want to achieve with your query.

Comment: @miracle173, in OP's case a left join with the same result as an inner join.

Answer (score 0):

Just add `DISTINCT`.

```
SELECT DISTINCT cc.co_id
      ,cc.title
      ,cc.subtitle
FROM ...
```

Answer (score 0):

since you want to select companies i'd do a subquery something like this:

```
SELECT  
      cc.co_id
      ,cc.title
      ,cc.subtitle

FROM tbl_company AS cc
WHERE  publish=1
AND (
cc.co_id in (select cm.co_id from  tbl_category_member cm where cm.cat_id  IN (14,16))
or  cc.co_id in (select lm.co_id from  tbl_location_member lm where lm.loc_id IN (1,2))
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Add DISTINCT to SELECT:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
  cc.co_id
  ,cc.title
  ,cc.subtitle

FROM tbl_company AS cc
LEFT JOIN tbl_category_member as cm ON cm.co_id = cc.co_id 
LEFT JOIN tbl_location_member as lm ON lm.co_id = cc.co_id 
WHERE publish=1
AND cm.cat_id  IN (14,16)
AND lm.loc_id IN (1,2)
```

You can also do the same with GROUP BY cc.co_id, but as I found out recently, not in all SQL Languages (looking at you MSSQL)

Comment: Are you talking about the MySQL "group by feature"? Isn't that deprecated?

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, what is deprecated is the implicit sorting by GROUP BY, the GROUP BY itself is not. Also I also believe that it isn't MySQL exclusive